# Putting Backbone.js in javascript anonymous closures

Tags: javascript, architecture, backbone.js, closures, anonymous

I am trying to put all my backbone.js files in javascript anonymous closures so that I can structure my code a bit better and also integrate require.js in the future.

Here's an example of what I am trying to do (only 2 files shown but I am willing to keep the same structure for the rest):

**main.js BEFORE:**

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
console.log('Closing view ' + this);
if (this.beforeClose) {
    this.beforeClose();
}
this.remove();
this.unbind();
};

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

initialize: function() {
    $('#header').html( new HeaderView().render().el );
},
  ...etc etc
```

**main.js AFTER (with anonymous closure):**

```
(function(AppRouter){
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
console.log('Closing view ' + this);
if (this.beforeClose) {
    this.beforeClose();
}
this.remove();
this.unbind();
};

//HERE, no way to instantiate AppRouter, won't work
var app = new AppRouter();

initialize: function() {
    $('#header').html( new HeaderView().render().el );
},
  ...etc etc
})(app);
```

**app-router.js BEFORE**

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

initialize: function() {
    $('#header').html( new HeaderView().render().el );
},
  ...etc etc
```

**app-router.js AFTER (with anonymous closure)**

```
(function(){
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

initialize: function() {
    $('#header').html( new HeaderView().render().el );
},
...etc etc
})(AppRouter);
```

so app-router.js being included before main.js, why is the object AppRouter 'undefined' in my main.js code? There is no way I could instantiate that object.

Answer (score 1):

the app variable is defined inside the function in main.js and being passed to same function where its not available.

ie

```
(function(AppRouter){ .....

var app = new AppRouter();

....}(app)
```

you need to pass AppRouter while calling the function

```
(function(AppRouter){ .....

var app = new AppRouter();

....}(AppRouter)
```

also as per app-router the AppRouter is not available in global context so you need to return the extended object like follow then it will be accessible across the app

```
var AppRouter = (function(){
return Backbone.Router.extend({

initialize: function() {
    $('#header').html( new HeaderView().render().el );
},
...etc etc
})();
```